# Compare CSV files using python

Tags: python, csv, comparison

Hi i need help in comparing two csv files...and get the matched records from two files into an output file...and unmatched records into another output file...
For Eg: my first csv file contains two columns Name and Salary with data as

```
A 20000
B 15000
C 10000
D 5000
```

2nd CSV file contains Name and Salary with data as

```
A 40000
D 10000
B 15000
```

my output should come as two files with matched file containing B 15000 B 15000 from file1 and file2 respectively
and 2nd file contains unmatched records as

```
A 20000,A 40000
C 10000,-------(no record in file2)
D 5000, D 10000
```

Comment: use https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map Seeing how you havn't tired anything yourself I'm pointing you in the right direction and I'm voting for closing this question as it's to broad and you should at least try to solve the issue on your own.

Comment: you can put your values into a dict with key for example `'A':20000` and then compare the value of the second file and if its grater than dict's value, then replace it with the new one

Comment: i have tried this script 
import csv
file1 = open("1.csv", "r")

reader1=csv.reader(file1)

reader1.next()

file2 = open("2.csv", "r")

reader2=csv.reader(file2)

reader2.next()

file3 = open("file3.txt", "w")

file4 = open("file4.txt", "w")

file1.seek(0,0)

file2.seek(0,0)

list1 = file1.readlines()

list2 = file2.readlines()

for i in list1:

    for j in list2:

        if i == j:

            file3.write(i)

            file3.write(j)

        else :

            file4.write(i)
            file4.write(j)
 but itz taking header also and plus in unmatched file comparison is done between all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f1_in = open("f1.csv","r")
f1_dict = {}
for line in f1_in:
    l = line.split()
    f1_dict[l[0].strip()] = l[1].strip()
f1_in.close()

f2_in = open("f2.csv","r")
f2_dict = {}
for line in f2_in:
    l = line.split()
    f2_dict[l[0].strip()] = l[1].strip()
f2_in.close()

f_same = open("same.txt","w")
f_different = open("different.txt","w")

for k1 in f1_dict.keys():
    if k1 in f2_dict.keys() \
    and f2_dict[k1] == f1_dict[k1]:
        f_same.write("{0}, {1}\n".format(str(k1)+" "+str(f1_dict[k1]),
                                         str(k1)+" "+str(f2_dict[k1])))
    elif not k1 in f2_dict.keys():
        f_different.write("{0}, {1}\n".format(str(k1)+" "+str(f1_dict[k1]),
                                              "------"))
    elif not f2_dict[k1] == f1_dict[k1]:
        f_different.write("{0}, {1}\n".format(str(k1)+" "+str(f1_dict[k1]),
                                              str(k1)+" "+str(f2_dict[k1])))

f_same.close()
f_different.close()
```

**Edit:**
To sort a dict by keys, before looping on keys (`for k1 in f1_dict.keys()`):

```
# get the keys as a list
my_keys = f1_dict.keys()
# sort it
my_keys.sort()
# use sorted list
for k1 in my_keys:
```

To sort a dict by values, before looping on keys:

```
# return a list of tuple : [(key1,value1),(key2,value2)]
my_zip = zip(f1_dict.keys(), f1_dict.values())
# now you have a list you can sort it :
my_sorted_list = sorted(my_zip, key=lambda value, value[2])
```

`key=lambda value, value[2]` means `my_zip` will be sorted using the second value of each tuple of the list.

```
# use sorted list
for t in my_sorted_list:
    # t is a tuple
    k1 = t[0]
    value = t[1]
```

Comment: getting an error 'list index out of range' in the line f1_dict[l[0].strip()] = l[1].strip()

Comment: How to modify the script so that it can take any number of columns...right now itz taking only 2 column comparison...and moreover i need my output file data to be sorted.

Comment: In this code i supposed all line in file 1 are full, maybe your file 1 has a line like "E" and no value after.

Comment: You can use a list/tuple as the value of the dict if you have more than one value to compare. To sort by key : you get the keys with (my_kyes = my_dict.keys()) then you sort it (my_keys.sort()). To sort by value (if not a list) , zip keys and values (my_list = zip(dict.keys(),dict.values())) then it's possible to sort it by values (my_sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda value: value[1]))

Comment: if you can cft...please make those changes in the above script and comment...i am a beginner in python script.

Comment: does it help you? If you're a beginner : in IDLE or IPython you can get help (dir: to know function of your variables, dir([]) or dir({}) or ...; help: to display a man page, help([].sort) or help({}.keys()))

Comment: Thanks cft i will try this and plus how can i compare if there are more than 2 columns in source and target file